# Materialize plugin breaks date and datetime selectors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, materialize

I've been breaking my head with the following problem... I have a basic and functional rails app to record events, I used scaffolds to build the model and all, users can record events with their datetime, everything works.  ***However, as soon as I add "Materialize" to the app, it breaks all the datetime, date, and time selectors in forms***.

After Materialize, the datetime_selector generated by Rails in my form just aren't actionable at all and they seem weird (Screenshots included)

– This happens if I install the gem manually or if I install it with bower.  I am aware that materialze has a special "datepicker" class for date_selectors. Using this makes no difference.

– I have no other CSS being applied to my form (I removed all scaffolds.css). If I try applying material design styles manually, the forms do work, but I can't use Materialize then.

Any thoughts on why this happens and how to fix it?

Screenshots:

[image: before materialize]

[image: after materialize]

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <% if @event.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@event.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this event from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @event.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :datetime %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :datetime, class: "datepicker" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :date, class: "datetimepicker-rails" %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :time %><br>
    <%= f.time_select :time %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :address %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :cost %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :cost %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :category %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tags %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :tags %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :image %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you followed all the sass instructions as per the Gem documentation? https://github.com/mkhairi/materialize-sass

Comment: Thanks for your reply @TomFast, I did follow them exactly. I also did try making it CSS instead of SASS with *=require, with the same results.

Answer (score 5):

*Hey! So I figured it out and I'm posting this here for anyone who has the same problem.*

If you use Materialize with a f.date_select in rails, it simply renders some unusable pixels on your view. Materialize documentation does mention that they use a special class for a date selector `class="datepicker"`. And so the Materialize documentation mentions the following usage for plain html:

```
 <input type="date" class="datepicker">
```

Which in ERB is equivalent to:

```
 <%= f.date_select :date, class: "datepicker"%>
```

Which I obviously tried to no avail, and so I was thrown off by this, until I decided to inspect the code (the relevant part of which I list below) for the example in the Materialize website and found the code to be slightly different to their instructions...

```
 <input type="text" class="datepicker"> #Notice the input type
```

which in ERB is:

```
    <%= f.text_field :date, class: "datepicker"%>
```

And *Voilà!!* **the date selector now works.**

Comment: But what about a `f.datetime_select` is there any way to make it work? Because it actually render separe ***dropdown*** controls for **month**, **day**, **year**, **hour** and **minute**.

Answer (score 3):

I would add to Carlos answer this, remember to initialize the Javascript using:

```
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
selectYears: 15 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year});
```

And for the form:

```
<%= f.text_field :date_in, class:"datepicker" %>
```

Hope it helps! this still working in materialize-sass (0.97.6)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue also.  For some reason, the datetime select objects were set to `display: none` after adding materialize CSS

Here is my workaround.  Add your own class around the datetime form

```
<div class="datetime">
    <%= f.label :time %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :time %><br>
 </div>
```

Then declare your own CSS in your application.css file

```
.datetime select {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: auto;
}
```